# Swatches on mobile not working

Tags: magento2, swatches

I have a problem with my site. When i select a swatch on mobile, the price of the product doesn't change. This is only a problem on the mobile version of the site and not present on the desktop version.

I get the following error:
cannot call methods on priceBox prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Answer (score 1):

I have found a sollution to the problem.

Make a new folder in your theme directory called: Magento_configurableProduct/view/frontend/web/js

And put the following file in the directory: configurable.js

Copy the file contents from the magento vendor directory(vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js) in the new file you just made.

Replace the below code under the _initializeOptions: function () {

```
priceBoxOptions = $(this.options.priceHolderSelector).priceBox().priceBox('option',  'openOnFocus', true).priceConfig || null;
```

Hope this helps someone.